# Passing Canvas' 2D Context in Dart

Tags: dart, parameter-passing, dart-html

I have a function that accepts *CanvasRenderingContext2D* as a parameter and does the drawing. Whenever I try to pass it, I get this:

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D is not assignable to CanvasRenderingContext2D
```

That function looks like this:

```dart
  void draw(CanvasRenderingContext2D context) {
  ...
  }
```

I thought everything is passed as a reference in Dart (just like JS), which shouldn't cause such problems. Is there a way to say I want a reference to the object and not the object it self? Or is there something else I should know?

**EDIT:**

The problem was that in one file I imported *dart:html* and in another I had *dart:dom*. The names for corresponding interfaces are the same but they are different.

Comment: are you using both dart:html and dart:dom ?

Comment: You are right. That was my problem. This error appeared before I realized that dart:dom and dart:html are not compatible with each other ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because you are using [dart:dom](http://api.dartlang.org/dom.html) and [dart:html](http://api.dartlang.org/html.html) in the same application. To avoid such errors you should import one of them with a namespace

```dart
#import('dart:html');
#import('dart:dom', prefix: 'dom');
```

then you can access code defined in both of them as

```dart
window     // dart:html window
dom.window // dart:dom window
```

for more information see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960937/whats-the-difference-between-darthtml-and-dartdom-package/8961468#8961468) answer